# iOS: How to add Assets folder inside a Framework and how to access them in code?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I create an iOS app and added a framework to it. The generated framework doesn't have an assets folder like the generate `Single View App`. So I made an Assets folder inside the framework folder and drag and drop it to xcode, choose the target as my framework.

I tried using the asset but the asset doesn't show up. Can show one show me how to correctly do this? is it possible to create an assets folder inside a framework?

I am very new to iOS so any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add *Asset catalog* to framework target as usual via *New File... > Resources*, but to get resource from such asset it needs to specify bundle explicitly, as in below example...

Assuming that `ImageProvider` is in framework target, the code could be

```
public class ImageProvider {
    // convenient for specific image
    public static func picture() -> UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: "picture", in: Bundle(for: self), with: nil) ?? UIImage()
    }

    // for any image located in bundle where this class has built
    public static func image(named: String) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: named, in: Bundle(for: self), with: nil)
    }
}
```

of course you can name such class anyhow.

Comment: is this also true even if I'm only accessin the assets within the same framework?

Comment: Yes, because by default resource searching is performed in `Bundle.main`.

Comment: Does this mean that to access assets I would now have to access it this way all the time everywhere? Cos then this `ImageProvider` class must be available to all framework/modules that I have in the project. isnt it?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones, in short - yes (for asset in any non-main bundle, framework, plug-in, etc). See updated code with some convenient examples.

Answer (score 2):

For SwiftUI use:

1. Add an Asset catalog to your framework project (eg, "Media.xcassets").
2. Add a resource, like a Color Set. Let's say you name your color "Thunder".
3. Create a file in your framework called "Color+Extensions.swift" (or whatever you like).
4. Inside this file do:

```
    import SwiftUI

    private class LocalColor {
      // only to provide a Bundle reference
    }

    public extension Color {
        static var thunder: Color {
            Color("Thunder", bundle: Bundle(for: LocalColor.self))
        }
    }
```

I imagine this works for other asset types as well.

In the project which is using your framework, once you have added the `import` for your framework, you should be able to just use the color normally:

```
    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.thunder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.

**First of all**, here's how you can create a Bundle to hold your assets like images.

**First**, create a new target:
Navigate to main Xcode menu, File => New => Target. Choose the "macOS tab" then
from "Framework & Library" select "Bundle".

[image]

Give it your desired name and hit Finish. You should see the bundle in your project folder.

**Second**, Configuration changes in build settings of Bundle:
Go to Build Settings on your bundle target and change the Base SDK to be iOS.

[image]

**Third**, Add images:
Add your images to the Bundle directly, no need to add an assets folder. Just drag and drop.

**Fourth**, build the bundle:
Choose your bundle as a destination and choose the generic iOS device and hit **Command + B**

[image]

**Fifth**, the .bundle will appear in your products folder under your project folder. Right-click on it and view it in Finder and then drag and drop it inside of your main project folder.

[image]

**Finally**, here's how I'd access the assets inside of your bundle.

```
// Empty UIImage array to store the images in it.
var images = [UIImage]()

let fileManager = FileManager.default
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("MyBundle.bundle") // Bundle URL
do {
  let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL,
 includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey],
 options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
  for item in contents { // item is the URL of everything in MyBundle imgs or otherwise.

      let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item.path) // Initializing an image
      images.append(image!) // Adding the image to the icons array
  }
}
catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

You will have the .plist file inside of your bundle, therefore, I suggest you handle this by a simple condition to check if the file name is `Info.plist` don't create an image out of it.

Here's how I handled it in a very trivial way.

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Glyphs.bundle")
    do {
      let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
      for item in contents {
        let imageName = item.lastPathComponent
        if imageName != "Info.plist" {
          let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item.path)
          icons.append(image!)
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      //print(error)
      showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: "Can't get the icons.")
    }
```

Comment: Note that this approach does not get any of the advantages of Xcode asset bundles which allow you to easily set different images for different screen resolutions, devices, and dark/light mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
scenario:

1. our framework will be consumed iOS/OSX
2. a lot of PNGs inside Framework
3. we want pngs in iOSApp && MacOs
4. let's assume out framework project and target is "MyCustomFramework.framework" (usual yellow icon..) already in our app

-

```
func filePathInFrameworkBundle(name: String)->String{

    let myBundlePath  = Bundle.main.bundlePath

    #if  os(iOS)

    let inMyFW = myBundlePath +
        "/Frameworks" +
    "/MyCustomFramework.framework"

    #elseif os(OSX)
    let inMyFW = myBundlePath +
        "/Contents/Frameworks" +
        "/MyCustomFramework.framework" + "/Versions/A/Resources"

    #else
    #endif

    let pathInBundle = inMyFW+"/"+name
    return pathInBundle
}
```

Now You can use THIS path in usual image loading calls.